Is there any way to comment out lines in a .rdp file?
Is there any way to comment out options in a .rdp Remote Desktop Connection file?
A good summary of the options can be found at https://www.donkz.nl/overview-rdp-file-settings/, but there's no mention of a comment syntax.
I've tried prefixes like #, //, ;, :.
The built-in mstsc.exe client seems to ignore the lines, but the Remote Desktop App complains about the format.

Couldn't connect
The RDP file provided is invalid. Make sure the file contains the full address and is formatted properly or contact your admin for help.


Have you tried the prefix ; (semi-colon)? Found on this page under the "Command File" section (and ChatGPT offers it as a suggestion).

@SaaruLindestøkke - ChatGPT is absolutely incorrect. A page for a client that isn’t RDP isn’t applicable to the client the author is using

That's why I didn't write it as an answer, just something to try out and note as "things that have been tried" in the OP.

I've added : and ; to the list of things I've tried, no success though.

For now I've settled on an old-school "REM" method of commenting out options.
REM full address:s:example.com

My guess is that Remote Desktop clients treat REM full address the same way they would any other unrecognised option, and ignore it for the sake of forwards-compatibility.
This method likely depends on the line being syntactically correct though, so may not work for arbitrary lines of text.

use :: like:
:: full address:s:hostname:port


I've tried :: on your suggestion, and mstsc is happy, but the Remote Desktop App still complains.
